# How to look at the past directory history the shell was in?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, history, zsh

Sometimes I like to look back in the command history to figure out what I was doing. Sometimes it would help to know what the cwd was for each command.

So, I'm wondering if there's some way to track this. I guess it's not too terrible to just dump the cwd in with the history in the history file, though it would have a lot of redundancy. So maybe it is better to configure it so that as part of rendering the prompt I can get zsh to write the current history index and the cwd into some other log. That is sufficient to store the information for use later.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I am aware, this would be something you would have to write yourself.  Things might get a little confusing if your file hierarchy changes at all though.  Anyway, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945288/saving-current-directory-to-bash-history) link might help you if you decide to write this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking in history file, you have to search for `cd` commands that stand **before** the command you watch, for understanding the correct execution location.

If you wanna track `pwd` in your history file, you will have to write some tracker.

Some ways to do it simply:

***.0*** Before of all, a simple way to find a location from your `.bash_history`:

```
grep <.bash_history '^cd \|theSpecificCommandISearchFor'
```

***.1***  `script` You could initiate a shell session by typing:

```
script -a /tmp/script-XXXX -t 2>/tmp/script-XXXX.tm
```

then, after ending your session, you could:

```
scriptreplay /tmp/script-XXXX.tm /tmp/script-XXXX
```

to see **all** what's was done.

This solution is *generic*, must work finely with every *interactive commandes line tool* (not only `bash`, nor `shell`, you could even save `vim` session with this tool).

You could add this at top of your `.bashrc` (if you use [bash](/questions/tagged/bash))

```
# THIS WILL LOG EVERYTHING ON A TYPSCRIPT FILE USING script TOOL! # 
if ! [[ "$(ps ho cmd $PPID)" =~ ^/usr/bin/script\ -t\ $HOME/.bash_script_ ]]
  then
    function runScript() {
        local sname=$HOME/.bash_script_$(date +%F_%H-%M-%S_$$)
        exec /usr/bin/script -t 2> $sname.tim $sname
        exit 0
    }
    runScript
  fi
```

***.2*** use `trap debug` to create an alternative history file, like:

```
trap 'echo "$PWD :: $BASH_COMMAND" >>/tmp/my_trapDebug_history' debug
```

Nota: This work under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), I don't know if nor how this work with other `shell` interpreter, like `zsh` or `dash`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a shell history extension that allows you to search history and shows you relevant results first based on the current directory, git repository, exit status, and host.

The project saves the extended history with PWD to `~/.resh_history.json` so you can also access it there directly.

You can install the project here: https://github.com/curusarn/resh
Launch it using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (replaces reverse search).
This is how the search application looks like:

[image: screenshot of the search application]

Disclaimer: I'm the creator of the project and this is shame-less self-promotion

Comment: This is neat, thank you for linking to your project!